# Variable is not recognized when called using sed in Gnuplot

Tags: variables, sed, gnuplot

I'm having a problem when i call a variable defined in gnuplot while using sed:

pi.plt

```
N= 10000
set term gif animate delay 80
set output "pi.gif"
j = 1
load 'pi2.plt'
```

pi2.pĺt

```
k = ` sed -n "$j p" pi.dat | cut -f3 -d ' ' `
set label 1 sprintf('Pi = %f', k) at graph 0.85, 0.85
set parametric
plot fx(t), fy(t), "pi.dat" every ::::j using 1:2 with points
j = j + 100
if (j < N+1) reread
```

The variable j, although is defined in gnuplot, is not recognized by sed and i keep getting the error "invalid command".
Can anyone help me solving this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
k = real(system(sprintf('sed -n "%d p" pi.dat | cut -f3 -d " "', j)))
```